# Java Calendar Object subtracts a month

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to fill a calendar object by doing this:

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(now);
```

It is now 2013-11-26 but when I print out

```
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

it will return 10.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you read the doc of the `Calendar` class ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Comment: If you want to display the month number to your user, or write it to a file, you should look into using a `SimpleDateFormat`.  The numbers returned by `Calendar.get` are really for internal use only, so you can do things like compare them to `Calendar.NOVEMBER`.

Answer (score 2):

You need not to fix it. It's `Calendar`  behavior.

[`cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

you are using `System.currentTimeMillis()`  that is the current month.

Return `10`  because the months starts from `0`. So 10 is the 11th month. I.e `Nov`

```
0-Jan
1-Feb
-
-
```

Answer (score 1):

See the javadoc of [Calendar.MONTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

> Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Calendar` constants defined for months:

```
if(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.NOVEMBER)
  System.out.println("It's November.");
```

The month field of a `Calendar` is zero-based, like an array index.

Answer (score 0):

`cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1`  - the numbering starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

You are printing Correct

```
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)
```

if month is `JAN`  it prints `0` , so for `NOV` ,`10`

Answer (score 0):

In contrast, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library provides a sensible month number. For example, `December = 12`.

```java
System.out.println( "Today's month number: " + new org.joda.time.DateTime(2013, 12, 28, 19, 0, 0).getMonthOfYear() );
```

When run…

```
Today's month number: 12
```